# This simple loop require a lot of time and I don't know why

Tags: c#, linq, loops, model-view-controller

I have this simple loop in a application. 
The records in the IEnumerable **rels** are 468, the records in the IEnumerable **analyzers** are 78, so each **analyzer** have 6 records in the **rels**

```
  IEnumerable<Reliability> rels = new Reliability().GetReliabilities()
    .Where(m => m.StartDate >= startDate && m.EndDate <= endDate && m.ContractId == ContractId && m.JobOrderId == JobOrderId && analyzers.Any(x => x.Id == m.AnalyzerId))
    .OrderBy(m => m.StartDate);

  List<ReliabilityModel> model = new List<ReliabilityModel>();

  foreach(Analyzer analyzer in analyzers)
  {
    long rel = rels.Where(m => m.AnalyzerId == analyzer.Id).Sum(m => m.ReliabilityHoursTicks);
    long tot = rels.Where(m => m.AnalyzerId == analyzer.Id).Sum(m => m.TotalHoursTicks);
    TimeSpan relHours = TimeSpan.FromTicks(rel);
    TimeSpan totHours = TimeSpan.FromTicks(tot);
    string relTime = ((int)Math.Truncate(relHours.TotalHours)).ToString() + ":" + relHours.Minutes.ToString("0#");
    string totTime = ((int)Math.Truncate(totHours.TotalHours)).ToString() + ":" + totHours.Minutes.ToString("0#");

    decimal value = Decimal.Divide(tot - rel, tot);

    model.Add(new ReliabilityModel
    {
      AnalyzerTagName = analyzer.TagName,
      AnalyzerTypeName = analyzer.AnalyzerTypeName, 
      ContractName = rels.Select(m => m.ContractName).FirstOrDefault(),
      JobOrderName = rels.Select(m => m.JobOrderName).FirstOrDefault(), 
      ReliabilityHours = relTime,
      TotalHours = totTime,
      Value = value.ToString("P4")
    });

  }
```

The problems is it's take a lot of time to be processed, about 200 seconds, and I don't understand why.
Any ideas?

Comment: I would try a couple of things:
1. change IEnumerable<Reliability> rels to List<Reliability> rels
2. Extract rels.Where(m => m.AnalyzerId == analyzer.Id) into a variable

Comment: Why do you check `analyzers` twice, in `Where` and `Any`? I guess, this `analyzers.Any(x => x.Id == m.AnalyzerId)` will slow down a lot. Also, `IEnumerable<Reliability> rels` seems to be evaluated every time when accessed in a loop. You can materialize it using `ToList()`

Comment: First you want to know whether the problem is in your query or in foreach. To do this, temporarily make rels a `List.Reliability`. This makes that all rels are already created before you do the foreach. Measure what takes more time: the making of the List, or the foreach

Comment: Also worth asking if this is EF, and if by any chance you could be lazy loading entities?

Comment: @DmitriTsoy thank you so much. Just change the IEnumerable to List and the process is under the second. Now I have to check all my application to avoid this behavior.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the rels are for "all" analyzers but in this point i filtered only a part of the analyzers.

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse in this point all the querys are done. The problem was in the IEnumerable, when I changed to List, the loop is done in under a second.

Comment: @devcpr in this point all the querys are done, and I don't use EF in this application.

Answer (score 1):

The golden rule of performance is to *measure*. If you have to coarse grained times to figure out what the problem is, then get more fine grained timings. Either by inserting more stopwatches, or by using [profiling tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/quickstart-cpu-usage-managed?view=vs-2019).

Some possible problems:

1. `rels` may be lazily evaluated (twice!) for each iteration of the loop. Use ToList to convert it to a actual list. (as mentioned by several people in the comments)
2. `rels` is filtered by the analyzer in each iteration. It would probably be more efficient group the reliabilities beforehand.

   relsByAnalyzer = rels.GroupBy(r => r.AnalyzerId).ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.ToList());

Comment: Yes, thank you. Just to add ToList improve the timing. And thanks again for the suggestion to group the Reliabilities.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer:

The problem is in

```
IEnumerable<Reliability> rels = new Reliability().GetReliabilities()...
```

without a ToList() at the end.

You call `GetReliabilities()` four times per Analyzer. Probably GetReliabilities doesn't just return a List or something, but really has to create an object that holds all Reliabilities.

Solution: add .ToList() before you start enumerating it. This way, the Reliabilities are created only once.

### Long answer

An object that implements `IEnumerable<...>` represents a sequence with the *potentional* to get the first element of the sequence, and as long as you have an element you can get the next one as long as there are next elements.

Be aware though, that enumerating the `IEnumerable<...>` can take some time, especially if creating the enumerated objects take some time.

So first you create an IEnumerable. This IEnumerable has not been enumerated yet.

```
IEnumerable<Reliability> rels = ...
```

Then you start enumerating your analyzers sequence:

```
foreach(Analyzer analyzer in analyzers)
{
    long rel = rels.Where(m => m.AnalyzerId == analyzer.Id).Sum(m => m.ReliabilityHoursTicks);
```

This means, that for the first analyzer, you create all elements that are in rels, and for every element you decide whether you want to keep it. From all kept elements you take the ReliabilityHoursTicks and sum them.

```
long tot = rels.Where(m => m.AnalyzerId == analyzer.Id).Sum(m => m.TotalHoursTicks);
```

You take the original query for rels, again create all element that are in rels, and for every element ... (etc)

Later:

```
  ContractName = rels.Select(m => m.ContractName).FirstOrDefault(),
  JobOrderName = rels.Select(m => m.JobOrderName).FirstOrDefault(),
```

Depending on how smart `GetReliabilities()` is, you either create one element of rels, or GetReliabilites fetches all elements of which you only use one

So per analyzer you call GetReliabilities four times. That is your bottleneck

Comment: Thank you for the long answer so I understood more about collection.